# Swift / how to create an int of an array.count

Tags: ios, swift

I'm downloading information from a blog with a xml parser. I need an `int` of how many blog entrys have been downloaded. There are 4 entrys.

```
       var posts = [EventPosts]()

       func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            print(posts.count)
            return posts.count
       }
```

Prints 0 and 4.

But:

```
        var intFromPosts: Int {
        return Int(posts.count)
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(intFromPosts) 
        }
```

Is always zero. How do I get an `int` from the array.count? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Your posts array is probably still emty at this stage of the objects construction, in viewDidLoad. Try putting print(intFromPosts) in viewDidAppear for example, or maybe even later in the program execution.

Comment: you were right. viewdidload gave 4. but how do I get `intFromPosts`to be finished downloading or have the functions calling `intFromPosts`to wait for it have finished downloading?

Comment: @DavidSeek You don't. That would block the thread that it's access from (in your case probably main thread) and would cause the application to freeze. You have to update information async.

Comment: There's many approaches, this is very broad. You can have a look at callbacks (completion handlers), or NSNotification, or delegation, etc. But basically, you never "wait", you use the data *when it becomes available*.